# Colleague commited suicide - is there anything I could have done to help?

Tags: death

One of my colleagues committed suicide.

We are an IT consultant company. When we have a contract, we will be deployed at a customer's site; one of our customers always put every consultant under microscope; it is not an official practice, but it has been happening. One may argue they have every right to do it as they are paying good money for our service.

This colleague of mine came under fire for raising too many Jira tickets. Someone came to her and complained about it in person. This resulted in a dramatic drop in her mood and shortly afterwards, she requested a transfer out of this company.

Two days later, she committed suicide, leaving her husband and a 4 year old daughter behind.

I noticed her drop in mood but I did not do anything.

Is there anything I could have done to help? I am asking myself what would have happened if I had invited her to a cup of coffee - might she have managed to pull it through?

Comment: Sorry for your loss but this isn't really what we do here.  We'd need to be psychic to now what would have made a difference and there isn't a canonic workplace way to handle someone taking criticism very hard.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a personal issue vs a workplace issue, and deals with high-level psychiatric/medical situations. If it would be dealt with, I don't think workplace is the stack for it. Don't want to be callous, but this is outside of the scope here, and you're more likely to get help you need via some other means.  This is not an attack on you for raising it, just that this just doesn't seem like something we are equipped to manage as "workplace advice."

Comment: It's doubtful the events at work were the sole contribute to her suicide. So you shouldn't feel bad in that regard.

Answer (score 23):

Depression is a **disease**.

A cup of coffee cannot fix a disease. A cup of coffee cannot cure cancer. A cup of coffee cannot cure depression.

I can guarantee you that coming under fire for her number of JIRA tickets did not cause her to commit suicide. Even if you could have stopped that person from walking through the door and chastising her, it would not have changed the outcome. What you saw was most likely the cultivation of months or maybe even years of pain, negative thoughts, and incredibly well-hidden emotions that she finally let go of.

I'm really sorry for your loss. Depression is especially hard because it's so hard to recognize and even harder to understand. My best advice for you is to go check in with a therapist about it if it's really upsetting you. Think of it as a gift to her--keeping your own mental health in check.

Comment: Ya that's basically what I told someone else in a comment reply.  It's sad really but as you mentioned, she was probably to a stage where there wasn't much anyone could have done.  if it wasn't that instance, something else would have triggered it later, especially if she wasn't getting any help for it.

Comment: While a cup of coffee won't fix depression, it can help people to fight against it. However, it is important to keep in mind that one should never ever try to fix someone, especially because it can go badly backwards (which happened last time someone untrained tried to fix me...). It is especially important to keep in mind that if somone considered suicide it is very difficult to help at all.

Comment: *"I can guarantee you that coming under fire for her number of JIRA tickets did not cause her to commit suicide."* I'm not sure you can *guarantee* anything in particular, especially since we don't know what may or may not have been happening outside the work, but in my non-expert opinion, it seems likely that it could've been the drop that spilled the cup that was already pretty full. So, I think you *might* be right in some things, but not with the certainty you seem to think.

Comment: @Midas Feel free to find your way through, many different forms of depression are covered. https://www.psychiatry.org/psychiatrists/practice/dsm

Comment: Depression is not the only thing that causes suicide

Answer (score 14):

If you're close to a coworker and notice that they're down, it might be appropriate to ask them about how they feel. If you aren't close to them, it's probably inappropriate to do so in a professional environment.

Mental health is a serious issue, and I don't mean to downplay that. But as a coworker, you did the correct thing by not getting involved.

Comment: Also, I highly doubt that this singular instance at work was the sole reason for suicide.  There could have been home issues, there could been family issues.  Suicide is something that is taken as a last measure when they feel there is no way out.  Her being scrutinized was probably the last straw of many other issues.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who has struggled with suicidal tendencies, and several attempts, I think I can offer some insight.

It's a form of insanity.  Yes, I know the preferred term is "mental illness" these days, but it does not seem strong enough a term.  What else is appropriate for wanting to end your own existence?

There are no reasons that will make sense to the anyone other than the person themselves, and few things can be done unless someone shows very clear signs, at which point, the thing to do is try to get that person to seek help.  Such clear signs are things like giving away prized possessions, talking with a sense of finality, and, oddly enough, a sudden upswing in mood.  The last is because the person has come to peace with ending their life and they know they won't be suffering for much longer.  It can even trigger a feeling of euphoria, which is particularly dangerous because it reinforces the person's resolve to take their own life.  Would you back down from a plan that made you so happy?

If there are no clear signs, there's nothing you can do.  You're not a professional.

If you were kind, you did enough and all that could be expected.  Sometimes it helps, sometimes it doesn't, but it never hurts.  You had no way of knowing where your coworker was.

The only thing I can say is if you ever notice anyone feeling down, share a kind word.  It may not help, but you never know how much of an effect of saying "are you okay?  I'm concerned" can have on a person.  That alone could snap them back enough to seek help.

Don't blame yourself for this, you could not have known.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to help, it would have been important to know her well, and recognise the symptoms as soon as possible.

Now this is based on my own experiences: it is really difficult to realise by yourself something is wrong, and if you have no experience you need to be very observant to have a chance at all.